# Razor View if statement incorrect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

My last 'if' statement is rendering as text. How can i fix that?

See how the grey highlighting for the 2nd 'if' statement completes on the end of the last 'if' statement?

[image: My Printscreenieeeee]

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Razor thinks that the previous `if` hasn't ended yet, since you're still inside the `<div>`s.

You need to prefix the `<div>`s with `@:` to prevent Razor from matching the tags.